# Android localise strings to es_US

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

I am trying to localise strings to es_US (Spanish in US).
I have string resources in folder values-es-rUS and language on device is set to Español (Estados Unidos), `Locale.getDefault()` returns `es_US`.
Even when everything seems to be correct, app doesn't pick up strings from values-es-rUS but it falls to values.

Did someone make it work?

EDIT: Solved. Can't mark my answer as accepted now.

Comment: make sure that both string resource files are named the same, for example res/values/strings.xml and res/values-es-rUS/strings.xml and that the resource names are the same "<string name="hello">Hello!</string>" and "<string name="hello">Ola!</string>" It's basic stuff, but sometimes you can forget it...

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in gradle build file configuration. I use resConfigs "en", "es" so build can exclude other resources. It seems that "es" excludes also "es_US".

When I changed it to resConfigs "en", "es_US" it started to work

Comment: Phew! I am working on a project where resConfig was already defined in build.gradle. Spent hours before I came across this. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

- Folder should be placed in  `res/values-es_rUS`
- `strings.xml` files must have same names in all strings localized
  *

[From here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) (table 2 - section 2)

## Language and region

> The language is defined by a two-letter [ISO 639-1](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) language code, optionally followed by a two letter [ISO 3166-1-alpha-2](http://www.iso.org/iso/prods-services/iso3166ma/02iso-3166-code-lists/list-en1.html) region code (**preceded by lowercase "r"**).
>
> The codes are not case-sensitive; the r prefix is used to distinguish the region portion. You cannot specify a region alone.
>
> This can change during the life of your application if the user changes his or her language in the system settings. See [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for information about how this can affect your application during runtime.
>
> See [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) for a complete guide to localizing your application for other languages.
>
> Also see the locale configuration field, which indicates the current [locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#locale).

Comment: Underscore in resource fails compilation

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

I'm sure you've looked at this, but it has everything you need on it. I followed the instructions step by step and was able to localize my strings.
Perhaps you named your values folder incorrectly? That would be my guess